# How do split only numbers from a given string of "$##,##,###.###" in JAVA

Tags: java, selenium

I am stuck with a problem of splitting just the numbers from a given input string 
take an example of a total bill of

> TOTAL  =  $19,67,456.45

Now, for the arithmetic calculations we need just the numbers removing the

> $    ,     .

and so every string which tries to come in the entire string of

> TOTAL=$##,##,##,###

Finally we should have just the numbers for performing arithmetic calculations on bill.
I tried to solve this as follows

```
    String price = "$12,23,44,555"
    String ArrArgs[] = price.split("");
    for (int i=2;i<ArrArgs.length;i++){
        if (ArrArgs.equals(".")){
            break;
        }
        if ((ArrArgs[i]).equals(",")){

        }else {
            strPrice = ""+strPrice+ArrArgs[i];
            System.out.println("Adding "+ArrArgs[i]);
        }
    }
```

BTW All I am doing is to automate a testcase in Selenium WebDriver for bills greater than $99,99,99,999. 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: $99,99,99,999. - that sort of numeric representation makes little sense. Surely you mean $999,999,999.00

Comment: try removing the $ from the value and use Double.valueOf(String_without_dollar_sign)

Comment: @yogx The $ sign cannot be removed since it is the Application Under Test (AUT), I was automating that to retrieve the value. Hope you get that

Comment: @ChiragPandit as stated in your question **Finally we should have just the numbers for performing arithmetic calculations on bill. I tried to solve this as follows**, i thought this approach might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do like this

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
Number number = format.parse("$19,67,456.45");
System.out.println(number.toString());
```

**Output**

```
1967456.45
```

Comment: Thanks a ton that solved my problem ^__^ never knew JAVA had classes for every different things. Thank you soooo much

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the `String.replaceAll` function:

```
String TOTAL = "$19,67,456.45";
System.out.println(TOTAL.replaceAll("[\\$,.]", ""));
```

The function takes a regular expression.

Comment: I just did not had classes for regular expressions in any language. I fear of it and just dont understand all those signs. Thanks btw for making that effort :)

Comment: Don't fear of it, just read a little bit about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression. The more you use it, the more things you will do with it! It's not always a good solution using regular expressions (for example for performance critical issues), but for small problems they are worth theirs weight in gold!